# Is there a tool for splitting german compound words in java?

Tags: java, string, text-processing, tokenize

I am sucessfully splitting Sentences into words with a `StringTokenizer`.

Is there a tool which is able to split compound words like `Projektüberwachung` into their parts `Projekt` and `überwachung` or even [some longer ones](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rinderkennzeichnungs-_und_Rindfleischetikettierungs%C3%BCberwachungsaufgaben%C3%BCbertragungsgesetz)?

The reason for splitting the compound words is that i want to do a text-extraction. I want to convert phrases like these `Projektplanung und -überwachung` into the two parts `Projektplanung` and `Projektüberwachung`. And splitting the compound word is my first step.

Comment: That seems like a pretty hard thing to do, because it would need to know that Projekt and planung are two valid words that are concatenated to form a single word. Without a dictionary, there is no way to know that projektplanung can be split, and that it must be split into projekt and planung. It could very well be Proj-ekt-plan-ung. And even with a dictionary, I guess some words could be found that are the concatenation of two other words, but can't be split. In English, for example, I wouldn't consider Sunday to be a compound word formed from sun and day.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[JWordSplitter](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jwordsplitter/)

Randomly saw this on synaptic this morning. Here is the description from the site:

"jWordSplitter is a small Java library that splits compound words into their parts. This is especially useful for languages like German where an infinite number of new words can be formed by just appending nouns ("Donaudampfschifffahrtskapitän")."

Usage is as simple as this:

```
String word = "Donaudampfschifffahrtskapitän";
AbstractWordSplitter splitter = new GermanWordSplitter();
Collection<String> splittedWords = splitter.splitWord(word);
```

Unfortunately, there is no pre-built library in the download section, but it is easy to build. Here is a short description how to do this in three simple steps.

1. Checkout the sources via SVN:

   `svn co https://jwordsplitter.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/jwordsplitter/trunk jwordsplitter`
2. Open the Maven Project e.g. in Netbeans
3. Build the library which includes the dictionary (jwordsplitter-3.2.jar, 300kB)

Answer (score 1):

I have always had a great dislike for the type of hyphenation in your example: `Projektplanung und -überwachung`.  :-(  So even though I agree with JB Nizet, that without a list or dictionary of simple non-compound nouns there is no way to know, maybe there is a way to  *make an intelligent guess*, in German at least.  Let's reunite Projekt and -überwachung!

You could create a list of **consonant-clusters**, and note where these clusters divide. e.g. *ktpl* in the first word of the pair would divide so: kt-pl. *Geschwindigkeitsbegrenzung* has `tsb` which divides ts-b.  I haven't thought it all the way through--and additional meta-data may be necessary.

The algorithm would find the most "centrally located" consonant-cluster in the word. E.g. it would ignore 'schw' and 'nd' and 'gr' and 'nz' and look to 'tsb' in *Geschwindigkeitsbegrenzung*.

Answer (score 0):

Lucene has a [Token Filter](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_1_0/api/contrib-analyzers/org/apache/lucene/analysis/compound/DictionaryCompoundWordTokenFilter.html) that can decompose compound words. Perhaps this could suit your needs ?